# C++ confusion about initializer of custom class

Tags: c++, class, initializer-list

Let's say I want to have a custom class called `Domain2D`. Domain would consist of vector of internal `Triangle` and an object called `Boundary2D`. `Boundary2D` would consist of list of `LineSegment` and each Triangle would consist of three `V2` objects. Each `V2` object would consist of two coordinates. Let's do this:

The following creates V2 class and a constructor for this class, so that I can define objects like `V2 vertex = V2 (5,-4);` Default value is `(0, 0)`.

```
class V2 {
public:
    long double x, y;
    V2(long double xx = 0, long double yy = 0);
};

V2::V2(long double X, long double Y) {
    x = X; y = Y;
}
```

The next thing I need is a line segment:

```
class LineSegment {
public:
    V2 v1, v2;
    LineSegment(V2 vv1 = V2(0, 0), V2 vv2 = V2(1, 0));
};

LineSegment::LineSegment(V2 VV1, V2 VV2) {
    v1 = VV1; v2 = VV2;
}
```

Default line segment consists of vertices (0, 0) and (1, 0). Then I need a triangle:

```
class Triangle {
public:
    V2 v1, v2, v3;
    Triangle(V2 vv1 = V2(0, 0), V2 vv2 = V2(1, 0), V2 vv3 = V2(0, 1));
};

Triangle::Triangle(V2 VV1, V2 VV2, V2 VV3) {
    v1 = VV1; v2 = VV2; v3 = VV3;
}
```

The default triangle consists of a standard simplex in 2D Cartesian coordinates: `(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1)`. We're almost done, we just need a boundary consisting of line segments:

```
class Boundary2D {
public:
    std::vector<LineSegment> l;
    Boundary2D(std::vector<LineSegment> ll = {});
};

Boundary2D::Boundary2D(std::vector<LineSegment> lll) {
    l = lll;
}
```

default boundary is empty (`{}`), so if needed, we can immediately `push_back(...)` on it.

Finally, a domain consists of boundary and a vector of triangles:

```
class Domain2D {
public:
    std::vector<Triangle> t;
    Boundary2D b;
    Domain2D(std::vector<Triangle> tt = {}, Boundary2D bb = Boundary2D({}));
};

Domain2D::Domain2D(std::vector<Triangle> ttt, Boundary2D bb) {
    t = ttt; b = bb;
}
```

Now here's the problem: the compiler is okay with the default empty vector of triangles, but it doesn't understand my need for the default empty boundary, which I tried to initialize with `Boundary2D bb = Boundary2D({})`. It says `<function-style-cast>: cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'Boundary2D'`. What am I doing wrong? Is this bad approach to create structures like this? What should the default initializer for the boundary look like if I want it to be empty by default? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can copy construct in default arguments. This works: `Domain2D(std::vector<Triangle> tt = {}, Boundary2D bb = {});`

Comment: Bundary2D already has a default constructor, so you could just change `Domain2D(std::vector<Triangle> tt = {}, Boundary2D bb = Boundary2D({}))` to `Domain2D(std::vector<Triangle> tt = {}, Boundary2D bb)`

Comment: Oh that makes sense! Why haven't I thought of this? Pity I couldn't find anything that would help me on google so I wouldn't waste space here. Thank you very much for the explanation!

Comment: @mnistic: that doesn't work, however Boundary2D bb = {} works, as Tobias suggested.

Comment: @user16320 Glad that it helped. Added an answer now for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference, the offending line is

```
Domain2D(std::vector<Triangle> tt = {}, Boundary2D bb = Boundary2D({}));
```

which tries to declare a constructor with default arguments.

Having taken a closer look at this, the compiler output is pretty straight-forward actually. You are literally trying to use a C-style cast to convert an initializer-list `{}` to an object of type `Boundary2D`. As no such conversion operator is defined, it doesn't work

Just replace it with the following and it shall work:

```
Domain2D(std::vector<Triangle> tt = {}, Boundary2D bb = {});
```